# Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.JSchemaReaderException: 'Error when resolving schema reference '#/definitions/Manager'

Tags: c#, json.net, jsonschema

I'm trying to load Redfish schema definitions to use for validating Redfish responses. I tried the sample from `[NewtonSoft][1]`.

```
        JSchemaPreloadedResolver resolver = new JSchemaPreloadedResolver();
        resolver.Add(new Uri("http://redfish.dmtf.org/schemas/v1/Manager.json"), File.ReadAllText(@"c:\redfish-json-schema\Manager.json"));

        // the external ref will use the preloaded schema
        // Failure happens here!
        JSchema schema = JSchema.Parse(File.ReadAllText(@"c:\redfish-json-schema\Manager.json"), resolver); 

        JToken json = JToken.Parse(@"JsonFiles\json2.json");

        IList<string> errorMessages;
        bool isValid = json.IsValid(schema, out errorMessages);
```

I get the following error

> Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.JSchemaReaderException: 'Error when resolving schema reference '#/definitions/Manager'. Path '', line 1, position 1.'

Looking at the schema file, the definitions seem to have the right values. These json files are downloaded from [Redfish](https://www.dmtf.org/standards/redfish). What am I missing?

Thanks in advance for your response.

Comment: Your code says "failure happens here", so maybe the problem is in "c:\redfish-json-schema\Manager.json", whose contents you did not show?

Comment: @Ether, I downloaded the json schema from [Link](https://www.dmtf.org/sites/default/files/standards/documents/DSP8010_2020.4.zip) and copied the json files to c:\ folder location. There are multiple json files, Manager.json seems to be the root schema with references to all the different versions of json thereafter.